# RPart function does not finish. How to improve timing?

Tags: r, decision-tree, data-science, categorical-data, rpart

I have an issue while trying to create a decision tree through `rpart`, it is taking too much time to complete.

I am not sure if I need to reduce dimensionality or factors in any feature of the given dataset.

Below you will find a `head` and `str` from the dataset. Also this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1omehDdn6s7Y9exxIoO9UB0bzP20hRoyT) to it.

```
   Funct.Area Environment ServiceType Ticket.Nature SLA.Result..4P. IRIS.Priority
2         FUN         DCF         FUN            SR              OK    Priority 3
5         APS         DCF         APS            SR          Defect    Priority 3
7         SEC         DCF         SEC            SR              OK    Priority 4
8         SEC         DCF         SEC            SR          Defect    Priority 4
9         FUN         DCF         FUN            SR              OK    Priority 3
10        SEC         DCF         SEC            SR              OK    Priority 3

'data.frame':   69250 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Funct.Area     : Factor w/ 27 levels "0","812","APS",..: 13 3 26 26 13 26 26 26 26 26 ...
 $ Environment    : Factor w/ 29 levels " WS","812","BULK",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ ServiceType    : Factor w/ 21 levels "APS","BULK","CNC",..: 8 1 18 18 8 18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ Ticket.Nature  : Factor w/ 5 levels "BULK","CHG","HK",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ SLA.Result..4P.: Factor w/ 5 levels "#¡REF!","#N/A",..: 5 3 5 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ IRIS.Priority  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Priority 1","Priority 2",..: 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 ...
```

My understanding is that rpart package can handle categorical variables until 32 different factors.

Is there any way to reduce processing time?

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rdwqvcwabyAMcA-kcrOIeyL9PQhsHf5E) of the R script

Comment: for factor variables all 2^(k−1) − 1 posible splits (k = number of levels) are tested. 6 factors * many levels * 70k observations == "very slow". Try to collapse some levels. Convert some factors to ordered if it makes sense and so on. Or use some other method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195021/computational-time-for-categorical-vs-continuous-regressors  i think this might answer your question

Comment: Hi, I've tried with this, as suggested by stats g and seems to be working. I should read more regarding the parameters of rpart function. Any link will be useful. Thanks.